# Is there a safe alternative to std::equal?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, stl-algorithm

`std::equal()` is unsafe because the function cannot know whether it will overrun the length of the second container to be compared. That is:

```
std::vector< int > v( 100 );
std::vector< int > w( 10 );
bool same = std::equal( v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin() );
```

...will result in a buffer overrun for `w`.

Naturally we can test for these things (`v.size() == w.size()`), but compilers like Visual Studio 2010 still report the function itself as unsafe. And indeed it *is* unsafe in some fundamental sense: a team of programmers of varying levels of experience will eventually forget to compare sizes.

A safe alternative is easy to implement.

```
template< typename Iter1, typename Iter2 >
bool equal_safe( Iter1 begin1, Iter1 end1, Iter2 begin2, Iter2 end2 )
{
    while( begin1 != end1 && begin2 != end2 )
    {
        if( *begin1 != *begin2 )
        {
            return false;
        }
        ++begin1;
        ++begin2;
    }
    return begin1 == end1 && begin2 == end2;
}
```

But is there a safe alternative in the standard library?

Comment: Safe alternative to do what exactly? Just compare two `std::vector`s? Or two iterator ranges?

Comment: @sftrabbit To do what std::equal() does. To compare two iterator ranges.

Comment: It's easy enough to write a safe_equal implementation if == does not satisfy your requirements.

Comment: [_When comparing entire containers for equality, operator== is usually preferred_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal)

Comment: I’m not sure I agree with this assessment, even though I understand the complaint: `std::equal` is fundamentally an algorithm working on *iterator ranges* and by its very nature, and like *all* other C++ algorithms on ranges, those ranges are not checked by the algorithm. There is an overwhelming consistency about this point in the standard library, so I think it’s quite hard to make an error about it. You get a uniform interface that behaves completely expectedly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Right, and it's good that if we know what we're doing, we can call the 'unsafe' version, which doesn't have to do 2 x `std::distance()` & hence will perform better for iterators for which distance is slow. However, it is also undeniably good that C++ is adding 'safe' versions taking 2 pairs of iterators, as this supports a wider variety of uses, where sources of iterators aren't always known & it's unnecessary churn to manually check distances.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In C++14, the standard library will contain a version of `std::equal` that takes two pairs of iterators, similar to your `safe_equal`. Same for `std::mismatch` and `std::is_permutation`.

Answer (score 9):

`vector` has an operator== that first checks the size. In your example, just use the condition `v==w`.

Comment: which means it's safe according to the OP's definition of safe.

Comment: Well, I thought it was clear, but for the op's example, "v==w" is safe.

Comment: @huskerchad I used vectors as an example because it's quick to create two with different sizes. But imagine that one is a list...

Comment: @OldPeculier, I believe all of the STL containers have an operator== that works this way. If your question is whether you can do this for arbitrary iterators, the answer is no, because there is no way to know the length of a sequence based only on a single iterator in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I have wanted such a feature myself. I have not been able to find any facilities in the standard library.

If you are willing to use boost. Boost.Range has equal which I think is what your are looking for http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/non_mutating/equal.html

Comment: Boost 1.54 (to be released in early July) contains four iterator versions of `equal`, `is_permutation` and `mismatch`. You can grab the code off the boost trunk today.

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem and solved it by checking size of vector before equal.

```
  std::vector< int > v( 100 );
  std::vector< int > w( 10 );
  bool same = (v.size() == w.size()) && std::equal( v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `std::lexicographical_compare` twice to determine if either sequence is less than the other.